# What recourse do I have if I was auto-enrolled into an employer's 401k plan despite opting out?

Tags: united-states, 401k

I started my new job on April 1, 2019 and at the first meeting with my manager I asked my new manager how I could dis-enroll or un-enroll from the 401K plan rather than be auto-enrolled @ 4%. He didn't know and he would get back to me. Through the entire month of April, I repeated my request several times and received the same response.

In May, I decided to be proactive and I contacted Merrill-Lynch (the administrator of the plan) and the CSR assured me that I would not be enrolled and that no money would be deducted from my paychecks.

Despite all of this my last paycheck showed a deduction of 4% that I was not expecting. So I contacted Merrill-Lynch CSR again and told them that I want to reduce my contribution to zero and to have my contribution refunded.

He mentioned that, since I'm over age 59-1/2, I can withdraw the amount deducted with no tax penalty and get it deposited to my bank account, but I am not sure I can trust that.

Today I called Merrill-Lynch again to check on it and the CSR today told me that he shows a zero balance in my account and he doesn't know where my money went or how I can go about getting my money back.

I'm getting no help from Human Resources at my employer.

Any advice on how I can proceed?

Comment: Did you check your bank account to see if the money got transferred? Maybe they actually did what you asked if the Merill account was zeroed out.

Comment: A nuclear option would be to contact the labor department who govern employment rules and regulations. If they feel you have a case, they will assign and advocate to you to investigate.

Comment: Every 401(k) plan I've ever been a part of has a web portal run by the administrator (Fidelity, Voya, etc) where I go in and choose the percentage to be deducted.  Merrill-Lynch must have such a site.  Try and set it to zero from there.

Comment: @RonJohn You have not seen every plan then. Some still operate with paper forms submitted to HR

Comment: @Eric good point.  OP, have you filed a paper form setting your contributions to `0%`?

Comment: Maybe the 4% money withheld on the last paycheck and sent to Merrill Lynch has been returned to the employer who will include it on the next paycheck you will receive.

Comment: Why would anyone opt out ? You're literally getting free money.

Comment: @xyious There is no mention of an employer match, so no "free money", just redirecting a portion of your own money

Comment: It's still free money. Just by not paying taxes on the income you're getting free money. Of course if you pay it out immediately you're paying the same. Still, at over 59 years old, unless your 401k is already big enough to put you into a higher tax bracket after retiring, you need to take the free money.

Comment: @xyious I still don't see where the free money is coming from if there is no employer match. 401k is tax deferred, not tax exempt. So you will either pay taxes going in (roth) or taxes coming out (traditional). Other than that we are assuming a lot of things about op (like the company offering a match, op doesn't need the money now because of medical reasons, or that they are close to 59 years old and can still get a 10-15 year growth in a bond fund).

Comment: Tax deferred means that you're paying taxes when you get distributions. Which means that unless you're going to be in a higher tax bracket when getting (required minimum) distributions than you are now when likely working full time, you're saving money in taxes. I have literally never even heard of someone who made more money from their 401k after retiring than they made working full time after the age of 40.

Comment: @xyious exactly, and you said "Just by not paying taxes on the income" but you are still paying taxes on it one way or another. With minimal growth because op is over 59, so any "savings" that they are are getting at this age is negligible because time is not on their side. But to come full circle, the answer to the question 'How do I proceed to not contribute to my 401k when I'm over 59' is not 'put money into your 401k'